# How Far Apart do Two Continents have to be to Consider the Body of Water Between Them an Ocean?

Tags: internal-consistency, geography

Let's say we have a world like earth. Our focus is on two continents. These continents are separated by an ocean. However, I want to travel between them to be that of relative ease. So, How much space must there be between continents to consider the water between part of an ocean?

Comment: This is a straightforward geography/earth science question.

Comment: Traditionally, an "ocean" had no (known) other side. That definition changed about 500 years ago, when people finally began blue-water navigation far enough to discover the other side. By then, the names were fairly well set already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This more a geological definition than a geographical one (at least today).  Oceanic crust is relatively thin and basaltic in nature (to oversimplify), spreads from a center that forms a ridge (Mid-Atlantic Ridge, for instance), and subducts under another crustal plate, often forming an extremely deep sub-ocean trench (as in Marianas Trench).

Continental crust, on the other hand, is part of and moves with a landmass.

If a body of water lies on continental crust (like most of the Mediterranean, for instance), it's not considered an ocean.  If it has oceanic crust, it is.

Of course, "part of" an ocean can also include areas that lie on continental crust -- for instance, the continental shelves are "part of" the oceans, but are also "part of" the continent they adjoin; various straits and gulfs are "part of" an ocean, but lie on continental shelf.  For clarity, continental shelf is sea floor that was dry land during the last major ice age; it's continental crust, but below sea level and flooded by ocean water.  The English Channel is only a few dozen miles wide, on continental crust (the shelf of Europe), but is "part of" the Atlantic ocean

Comment: So the ocean between the two continents cou;d be only a couple miles wide and still be considered an ocean so long as the crust is oceanic?

Comment: -1 Please avoid answering off-topic questions.

Comment: The Mediterranean Sea has oceanic crust, [probably the oldest on Earth](https://www.livescience.com/55827-oldest-oceanic-crust-mediterranean-sea.html).

Comment: @overlord-ReinstateMonica I didn't see this as off topic -- "is this an ocean or not" seems legitimately worldbuilding.

Comment: @ZeissIkon As a moderator has stated, it's a geography/earth science question.

Comment: @overlord-ReinstateMonica About an hour after I'd answered.  Also, I tried and can't delete my answer, because it's been accepted.  And the question still isn't on hold...

Comment: @ZeissIkon Sometimes it takes an hour to put a question on hold, and sometimes it can take days. There's also the chance that others won't agree with me that the question is off-topic, which is fine because majority rules here and I'm aware that I'm not the only one with an opinion.